# How to search and access efficiently certain cells in a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame structure

```
      clientID  month  savings
0         10      2       15
1         20      2        2
2         30      2       10
3         40      2        5
4         50      2        7
5         60      2        9
6         10      3       10
7         20      3       10
8         30      3       11
9         10      4       13
10        30      4       15
11        40      4       16
```

and I would like to transform it into a new DataFrame that looks like this

```
    clientID   2     3     4
 0     10     15    10    13
 1     20      2    10  NULL
 2     30     10    11    15
 3     40      5  NULL    16
 4     50      7  NULL  NULL
 5     60      9  NULL  NULL
```

I did solve the problem, but in a very non-python like code, and I imagine this is why is running so slow (my initial dataframe has more than 2 million lines). 
This my code:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'clientID': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 10, 20, 30, 10, 30, 40], 
                   'month': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
                   'savings': [15, 2, 10, 5, 7, 9, 10, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16]})
 myDF = pd.DataFrame(df['clientID'].unique(), columns = ['User'])
 columnsToAdd = df['month'].unique()
 for col in columnsToAdd:
     columnName = str(col)
     myDF[columnName] = 'NULL'
     #indexes in df for which month = col
     idxMonth = df[df['month']==col].index.tolist()
     print(columnName, '\n')
     #User IDs for which month = col
     idxlabel = df['clientID'].loc[idxMonth]

     for i in np.arange(0, len(idxlabel)):
          zidx = myDF[myDF['User'] == idxlabel.iloc[i]].index.tolist()        
          myDF[columnName].loc[zidx] = df['savings'].iloc[idxlabel.index[i]]
```

can you please suggest an efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: BTW, you should tag `pandas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution from `pivot_table` PS: to make index become column by using `.reset_index()`

Option 1

```
pd.pivot_table(df,values='savings',index=['clientID'],columns=['month'],aggfunc='sum')
Out[429]: 
month        2     3     4
clientID                  
10        15.0  10.0  13.0
20         2.0  10.0   NaN
30        10.0  11.0  15.0
40         5.0   NaN  16.0
50         7.0   NaN   NaN
60         9.0   NaN   NaN
```

---

Option 2
using `unstack`

```
df.set_index(['clientID','month']).unstack(-1)
Out[432]: 
         savings            
month          2     3     4
clientID                    
10          15.0  10.0  13.0
20           2.0  10.0   NaN
30          10.0  11.0  15.0
40           5.0   NaN  16.0
50           7.0   NaN   NaN
60           9.0   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Option 1 could just be `df.pivot(index='clientID', columns='month')`.

Comment: @Abdou in case he have multiple saves under one cust within one month ~ :), But you are right ~ :)

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved me a lot of time!

Comment: I wasn't aware of the accept button, this is the first time I'm asking a question here.

Comment: @Ame.Lia np, right now you know how this site works. Happy coding :)