# Creating a pandas Dataframe from a list of Dictionaries, dictionary keys as columns

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

not sure if the title is explanatory enough.

I have a list of dictionaries from which I want to create a dataframe. For simplicity the list is:

```
list=[]

DIC1={'value': 69.0, 'time': 10, 'from': 'Mexico', 'signal_name': 'Part1'}
DIC2={'value': 65.0, 'time': 10, 'from': 'Mexico', 'signal_name': 'Part2'}
DIC3={'value': 60.0, 'time': 11, 'from': 'Mexico', 'signal_name': 'Part1'}
DIC4={'value': 67.0, 'time': 10, 'from': 'Mexico', 'signal_name': 'Part3'}
DIC5={'value': 69.0, 'time': 11, 'from': 'Mexico', 'signal_name': 'Part2'}
DIC6={'value': 70.0, 'time': 12, 'from': 'Mexico', 'signal_name': 'Part1'}
DIC7={'value': 68.0, 'time': 12, 'from': 'Mexico', 'signal_name': 'Part2'}
DIC8={'value': 71.0, 'time': 11, 'from': 'Mexico', 'signal_name': 'Part3'}
DIC9={'value': 50.0, 'time': 12, 'from': 'Mexico', 'signal_name': 'Part3'}

list=[DIC1,DIC2,DIC3,DIC4,DIC5,DIC6,DIC7,DIC8,DIC9]
#Convert to Dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame(list)
```

If I simply convert the list of dictionaries to a dataframe like in the example above I get a dataframe like:

```
    from    signal_name time    value
0   Mexico  Part1       10      69.0
1   Mexico  Part2       10      65.0
2   Mexico  Part1       11      60.0
3   Mexico  Part3       10      67.0
4   Mexico  Part2       11      69.0
5   Mexico  Part1       12      70.0
6   Mexico  Part2       12      68.0
7   Mexico  Part3       11      71.0
8   Mexico  Part3       12      50.0
```

But I'm trying to get a filtered table, I guess kind of a pivot table? Something like:

```
    time    from    part1(value)    part2(value)    part3(value)
0   10      Mexico      69.0            65.0            67.0
1   11      Mexico      60.0            69.0            71.0
2   12      Mexico      70.0            68.0            50.0
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of pivot table

```
df.pivot_table(index=['from','time'],columns=['signal_name'],values=['value']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
               from time value            
signal_name              Part1 Part2 Part3
0            Mexico   10  69.0  65.0  67.0
1            Mexico   11  60.0  69.0  71.0
2            Mexico   12  70.0  68.0  50.0
```

If you dont want value as separate header then pass values parameter as a string i.e

```
df.pivot_table(index=['from','time'],columns=['signal_name'],values='value').reset_index()
```

```
signal_name    from  time  Part1  Part2  Part3
0            Mexico    10   69.0   65.0   67.0
1            Mexico    11   60.0   69.0   71.0
2            Mexico    12   70.0   68.0   50.0
```

Comment: one simple tips for op: next time when you @MinoruTsuru asking question do google first , I just answered the same question twice this morning ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002443/how-to-search-and-access-efficiently-certain-cells-in-a-dataframe-in-python/46002526#46002526

Comment: @Wen sometimes the question they ask doesn't end up in the answer they are looking for in google. Usually they search for questions in google na so. It would be really nice if SO search for similar outputs and then show them in already asked question with some nlp.

Comment: As you saw...Op mentioned `pivot_table` :)

Comment: @Wen Thanks for the tip, actually i did spend some time looking for the answer to my problem. I don't usually post a question unless I really cannot find the answer. In this case, you did answer the same thing however the other question's title was completely different from mine. I guess the biggest issue here was that I actually did not know how to ask my question and indeed I mentioned pivot tables but was not really sure about it as all the searches i did for pivot tables and pandas led me to things that i could not relate to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Solution from `unstack`

```
df.set_index(['from','signal_name','time']).unstack(-2)
Out[437]: 
            value            
signal_name Part1 Part2 Part3
from   time                  
Mexico 10    69.0  65.0  67.0
       11    60.0  69.0  71.0
       12    70.0  68.0  50.0
```

Comment: We were so close really nice

Comment: @Bharathshetty I will delete my second , So plz keep you answer here :-)

Comment: @Wen what is more efficient then? unstack or pivot_table?

Comment: @MinoruTsuru should be unstack, if you working with large data set do not using pivot_table

Comment: @Wen, I'm trying to use unstack instead of pivot_table now, but I'm running into a problem. The unstack solution puts the index as [from,time] whilst pivot_table's index is just a number and 'from' and 'time' exist as a separate column, since i plan to run do things to the df based on 'time', is there a way to unstack it in the same way? (i tried changing the levels of unstacking but i always get double indexes)

Comment: @MinoruTsuru Hi , can you show the expected out put ? Or maybe we can open a new question about it :)

Comment: I will open a new question as this seems to be unrelated. Thanks!